# Array Operations to augment image Python cv2 using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

Given X is a Numpy Array X.shape =(1, 96, 96, 3),  Basically an Image read from CV2 . I am looking for simpler articulation of a augment operation.

Could you please explain what the following lines of code does

```
b=X[:, ::-1, :, :]
c=X[:, ::-1, ::-1, :]
d=X[:, :, ::-1, :]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X[::-1]` indexing applies: indices of `X` from first to last in steps of `-1`.

- `b=X[:, ::-1, :, :]` - Reverse image up/down.
- `c=X[:, ::-1, ::-1, :]` - Reverse image up/down and left/right.
- `d=X[:, :, ::-1, :]` - Reverse image left/right.

---

Remark:
`::` is not an operator, it's actually two `:` operators  one after the other.
`X[::-1]` is the same as `X[ : : -1]`.
Refer to [Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) documentation.

> The basic slice syntax is i:j:k where i is the starting index, j is the stopping index, and k is the step.
>
> If i is not given it defaults to 0
>
> If j is not given it defaults to n

Writing `[: : -1]`, omits `i` and `j`, and sets `k` to `-1`.
The syntax means: "from index `0`, take all elements, with step `-1`", that gives all elements in **reverse** order (all elements along this axis).

---

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Build input:
im = cv2.imread('chelsea.png')
im = cv2.resize(im, (96, 96))
X = np.empty((1, im.shape[0], im.shape[1], im.shape[2])).astype(np.uint8)
X[0, :, :, :] = im

b = X[:, ::-1, :, :]
c = X[:, ::-1, ::-1, :]
d = X[:, :, ::-1, :]
```

---

Result:

im:
[image]

b:
[image]

c:
[image]

d:
[image]

---

Note:
I kind of ignored the fist index because the dimension is `1`.
In case of multiple frames, it's common for the fist index to apply the number of frames.

Comment: Got the output, could you please elaborate with respect to What Happens in the multi dimensional array.
Trying to WhiteBox it

Comment: It's the same as in 1D array, but each dimension has separate indexing. In case `X` is 2D, `X[:, :]` equals `X`, `X[::-1, :]` reverse the first dimension, and keep second as is, `X[:, ::-1]` reverse the second dimension and keep the first as is, `X[::-1, ::-1]` reverses first and second dimension.

Comment: In case `X` shape is `(10, 10)`, you can also write `X[10:0:-1, 10:0:-1]`

Comment: To clarify it further, `::` is not an operator, it's actually two `:` operators one after the other. I edited my answer.